# pypbc + python3 + ubuntu + windows pycharm "Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault"

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04

```
import faulthandler
faulthandler.enable()

from pypbc import *
# from utils import hash_nosafe
import datetime
import hashlib

Hash1 = hashlib.sha256

#这里的内容就可以换成pbc中param文件夹下的几种曲线参数了，但是“”“是要保留的哦。
stored_params = """type a
q 8780710799663312522437781984754049815806883199414208211028653399266475630880222957078625179422662221423155858769582317459277713367317481324925129998224791
h 12016012264891146079388821366740534204802954401251311822919615131047207289359704531102844802183906537786776
r 730750818665451621361119245571504901405976559617
exp2 159
exp1 107
sign1 1
sign0 1
"""

# 密钥生成算法，输入安全参数qbits和rbits，返回[params, g, pk, sk]
# def KeyGen(qbits=512, rbits=160):
def KeyGen():
    params = Parameters(param_string=stored_params)   #参数初始化
    pairing = Pairing(params)  # 根据参数实例化双线性对
    # 返回公共参数，PEKS是对称双线性对，G1=G2,二者的生成元是一样的，G1同样可以替换为G2
    g = Element.random(pairing, G1)  # g是G1的一个生成元
    sk = Element.random(pairing, Zr) # 私钥是一个素数域Zp内的随机数
    pk = Element(pairing, G1, value=g ** sk)   # 公钥是[g, h = g^α] α=sk
    return [params, g, sk, pk]

params = Parameters(param_string=stored_params)
pairing = Pairing(params)

class Pkeet(object):
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.params = params
        self.pairing =  pairing
        self.g = Element(self.pairing, G1, g)
        # self.sk = Element(self.pairing, Zr, value=int(sk, 16))
        # self.pk = Element(self.pairing, G1, value=pk)
        # 随机数r的长度
        self.r_len = 42
        # 随机数m的长度
        self.m_len = 130

    def enc(self, pk, data):
        # m = str(data).encode('utf-8').hex()
        # m = str(data)
        element_m = Element(self.pairing, G1, str(data))

        r = Element.random(self.pairing, Zr)  # 定义一个Zp内的随机数r
        U = Element(self.pairing, G1, self.g ** r)
        V = Element(self.pairing, G1, element_m ** r)
        W = Element(self.pairing, G1, pk ** r)

        # hash_W是hex字符串
        # hash_W = hash_nosafe(self.m_len+self.r_len, str(U), str(V), str(W))
        hash_W = Hash1((str(U)+str(V)+str(W)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        element_hash_W = Element.from_hash(self.pairing, G1, hash_W)
        hex_m = str(data).encode('utf-8').hex()
        W_m = hex(int(str(element_hash_W), 16) ^ int(hex_m, 16))

        W_r = hex(int(str(element_hash_W), 16) ^ int(str(r), 16))

        W = (W_m, W_r)

        return (U, V, W)

    def dec(self, sk, data):
        U, V, W = data
        W_m, W_r = W
        # sk = Element(self.pairing, Zr, value=int(sk, 16))
        U_x = Element(self.pairing, G1, U ** sk)
        hash_W = Hash1((str(U) + str(V) + str(U_x)).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        element_hash_W = Element.from_hash(self.pairing, G1, hash_W)
        dec_m = hex(int(str(element_hash_W), 16)^int(W_m, 16))
        dec_r = hex(int(str(element_hash_W), 16)^int(W_r, 16))
        # print(dec_m)
        dec_m_1 = bytes.fromhex(dec_m[2:])
        dec_m_2 = dec_m_1.decode('utf-8')
        element_m = Element(self.pairing, G1, dec_m_2)
        element_r = Element(self.pairing, Zr, int(dec_r, 16))

        U1 = Element(self.pairing, G1, self.g ** element_r)
        V1 = element_m ** element_r

        # TODO V = m^r,这个程序里面不等于, 不知道为啥
        # if U == U1 and V == V1:
        if U == U1:
            msg = dec_m_2
            return msg
        return False

    def equal_test(self, C1, C2):
        U1, V1, W1 = C1
        U2, V2, W2 = C2
        rst1 = self.pairing.apply(U1, V2)
        rst2 = self.pairing.apply(U2, V1)
        if rst1 == rst2:
            return True
        return False
def test_equal():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    [params, g, sk, pk] = KeyGen()
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("KeyGen运行时间", end - now)


    pkeet1 = Pkeet(g)

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    result1 = pkeet1.enc(data="lable: 16", pk=pk)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("加密运行时间", end - now)

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    pkeet1.dec(sk, result1)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("解密运行时间", end - now)

    # print(pkeet1.dec(sk, result1))

    [params, g, sk, pk] = KeyGen()
    pkeet2 = Pkeet(g)
    result2 = pkeet1.enc(data="lable: 16", pk=pk)


    # print(pkeet1.dec(sk, result2))
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    rst = pkeet2.equal_test(result1, result2)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("等值测试运行时间", end - now)

    print(rst)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_equal()
```

When I tried to implement the [equivalence test scheme](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-11925-5_9) using pypbc, I got the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

ssh://root@192.168.221.130:22/usr/bin/python3 -u /code/python_pkeet/main2.py
KeyGen运行时间 0:00:00.004719
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f3f2bf20740 (most recent call first):
  File "/code/python_pkeet/pkeet2.py", line 51 in enc
  File "/code/python_pkeet/main2.py", line 22 in test_equal
  File "/code/python_pkeet/main2.py", line 49 in <module>
```

Process finished with exit code 139.

Can you tell me what this is all about?

Is there a better way to implement this scheme?

Comment: It's a lot of code. Given the information that you've got from the error, could you narrow down the code to just those bits you think are most relevant? Even if you have to debug a bit and put some try/catches around there, it would certainly help anyone who might be able to answer this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I refer to the library pypbc, which is a probabilistic thing. Sometimes it runs normally and sometimes it runs incorrectly, because it is linked to the PBC Library of C + +. You can't locate the specific error using python. You can only know that the error location is this line of code, element (self. Pairing, G1, str (data))